# Training a model on GPU is very slow

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I am using `A100-SXM4-40GB Gpu` but training is terribly slow. I tried two models, a simple classification on cifar and a Unet on Cityscapes. I tried my code on other GPUs and it worked totally fine, but I do not know why training on this high capacity GPU is super slow.

I would appreciate any help.

Here are some other properties of GPUs.

```
GPU 0: A100-SXM4-40GB
GPU 1: A100-SXM4-40GB
GPU 2: A100-SXM4-40GB
GPU 3: A100-SXM4-40GB
```

- Nvidia driver version: 460.32.03
- cuDNN version: Could not collect

Comment: Are you sure the GPU is being used? Is it free before training?

Comment: I am sure that the GPU is free, but something that I am wondering about is that while my model is training, when I check nvidia-smi it dose not show any process on any gpus

Comment: So, the GPU is not being used. What is the output of `torch.cuda.is_available()`?

Comment: I set this line  `self.device = torch.device(f'cuda:{self.gpu}' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')` in my code and I thought since I set `self.gpu` as the name of gpu that I wish to run on it, it is implemented on GPU.  I would check it now.

Comment: Yes, it is running on CPU

Comment: Why should I do then? Why it dose not read the gpu that I assigned in my code?

Comment: I'll repeat my question: "What is the output of `torch.cuda.is_available()`?" Or, if you prefer, what is the value of `self.device`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answer. Before trying your answer, I decided to uninstall anaconda and reinstall it and this solved the problem.

Comment: This is because you probably had a pytorch version incompatible with your NVIDIA driver

Answer (score 0):

Call `.cuda()` on the model during initialization.

As per your above comments, you have GPUs, as well as CUDA installed, so there's no point of checking the device availability with `torch.cuda.is_available()`.

Additionally, you should wrap your model in `nn.DataParallel` to allow PyTorch use every GPU you expose it to. You also could do `DistributedDataParallel`, but `DataParallel` is easier to grasp initially.

Example initialization:

```
model = UNet().cuda()
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
```

Also, you can be sure you're exposing the code to all GPUs by executing the python script with the following flag:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3 python3 train_unet.py
```

Last thing to note - `nn.DataParallel` encapsulates the model itself, so for saving the state_dict, you'll need to reach module inside DataParallel:

```
torch.save(model.module.state_dict(), 'unet.pth')
```

Comment: It is not true that "there's no point of checking the device availability with `torch.cuda.is_available()`". BTW, one doesn't even need CUDA installed to have PyTorch working on GPU. This is not what this command checks.

Comment: From PyTorch documentation: torch.cuda.is_available() - "Returns a bool indicating if CUDA is currently available."

Comment: Exactly. It is not about "being installed", but about "being available". CUDA is delivered together with PyTorch (hence, no need for installation), but one needs to be sure that it is compatible with the NVIDIA driver, otherwise CUDA won't be available.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But before uninstalling and then installing anaconda, first I checked the cuda version of the NVIDIA driver that was `11.2`, then I created a new-env using conda and installed pytorch with the same cuda version and it didn't help unless I uninstalled conda and reinstalled it again.